# Running Liquibase from inside a JAR. How do I tell it to look for the change set via classpath (also in the JAR) instead of filename?

Tags: java, scala, jar, classpath, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase in my Scala application which is packaged in a JAR using `sbt assembly`.  When the changelog location is supplied using a local file path, everything works fine.  In order to deploy using only the JAR, I'd like it to look inside the JAR instead.  How can I do this?

Current Setup:

`build.sbt` includes `"org.liquibase" % "liquibase-core" % "3.3.5"` as a dependency

Run:

`val liquibaseChangeLog: String = (from config)
val liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(liquibaseChangeLog, resourceAccessor, liquibaseConnection)
liquibase.update(new Contexts())`

I'd like to set `liquibaseChangeLog` to a classpath like `org/my_org/my_project/changelog.xml` but I get an error:

`Exception in thread "main" liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: org/my_org/my_project/changelog.xml does not exist
liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:100)
liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:17)`

Looking through the Liquibase source in this stack trace, I see that it explicitly wants a file.  Is there a way to look in the JAR instead?

Comment: Did you try `classpath:org/my_org/my_project/changelog.xml`?

Comment: I did, thanks.  Based on other SO posts, that seems to be specific to Spring, which I am not using.

Comment: IDK what your current resourceAccessor is but you might look at the `liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor` class if your not already using it